# Short creative writing story about a man being followed/ taunted/ possibly haunted (?) by a water droplet through this journey through the desert

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this short story back in high school (2018/2019?).

The story goes a man is going on a journey with a backpack on his back through the desert. In his backpack there’s a water droplet that acts humanly towards him, mocks, taunts, loves, hates, creates mischief, even seduces him(?). He arrives on a train station, there, the water droplet causes trouble.

The water droplet enters the (public) drinking fountains & those that drink from it start becoming ill/ sick of from it, this stresses the man out & he gets off the train & continues his journey until he entered a old, raggedy home (i believe this was his destination).

Inside the home, the water droplet starts becoming sick. It becomes cold, the whole houses freezes, the water droplet has become ice, the man is becoming worried & even trying to take care of it. The water droplet is short tempered, becoming spikes that hurt the man.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Did you read this online, in a magazine, or in an anthology?